# Trinocular mount for Sony Alpha cameras

Tags: macro, sony, microscopy

I would be interested about mounting my Sony A7r3 to an Amscope microscope. I don't have a microscope yet, but I would be interested about a trinocular one.

I could not find any mounts to allow my Sony to be attached onto the photo port (not eyepiece). Customer support can only advise about mounts for Nikon cameras.

Is there anything available I could use to make it work with sony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for "microscope camera adapter" on your favorite shopping sites. The same adapter should fit either eye-piece or camera port. The cheaper adapters have no optics. Without optics, images will have heavy vignetting.

Many of the microscope-camera adapters have T2 screw mounts on the camera side, including the AmScope model. Use a T2-NEX adapter, instead of T2-Nikon or T2-EF, to fit it to your camera.

[image: adapter stack]

See also:

- YouTube: [Attaching your DSLR Adapter to your Microscope](https://youtu.be/pzpHh1PQAEM) (AmScope)
- [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000/75526)